# Checking if cin fails for strings that start with numbers

Tags: c++

I am sure I am missing on a very simple thing here. My code looks something like this. It just checks what is the type of triangle.

```
try
    {
        double FirstSide,SecondSide,ThirdSide;
        cout<<"Enter the first side: ";
        cin>>FirstSide;

        if(cin.fail())
        {

            throw invalid_argument("Your input doesn't look to be a number.");
        }

        if(FirstSide > numeric_limits<double>::max() || FirstSide<0)
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Input is out of range.");
        }
        cin.ignore(); // Used afterwards, just to check

        cout<<"Enter the second side: ";
        cin>>SecondSide;

        if(cin.fail())
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Your input doesn't look to be a number.");
        }

        if(SecondSide > numeric_limits<double>::max() || SecondSide<0 )
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Input is out of range.");
        }

        cout<<"Enter the third side: ";
        cin>>ThirdSide;

        if(cin.fail())
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Your input doesn't look to be a number.");
        }

        if(ThirdSide > numeric_limits<double>::max() || ThirdSide < 0)
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Input is out of range.");
        }

        // Check for equilateral
        if(FirstSide == SecondSide == ThirdSide)
        {
            cout<<"The triangle is equilateral. ";
        }

        else if(FirstSide == SecondSide || SecondSide == ThirdSide || FirstSide == ThirdSide)
        {
            cout<<"The triangle is isosceles.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"The triangle is scalene. ";
        }


    }
    catch(invalid_argument& error)
    {
        cerr<<error.what()<<" Will now exit. "<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

If I input `2p`, I get the output: `Enter the second side: Your input doesn't look to be a number. Will now exit.`

Since the input is invalid for FirstSide, `Enter second side:` should not actually be printed. I am aware of the fact that compiler might be taking `2` for `FirstSide` and trying to assign `p` to `SecondSide` and hence the behaviour. If I ignore the values in stream (by using `cin.ignore()`, I actually get no error).

My question is how do I get my input correct for such cases like `2p` or `1k`?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Another question has popped up from the comments, How is the `FirstNumber > numeric_limits<int>::max()` comparison actually working if the value has already been assigned to `FirstNumber` ? 
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh279678.aspx

Comment: I am not sure, whether the comparison `SecondSide > numeric_limits<int>::max()` makes sense. Once the value is assigned to a `int`, it can only be `< = numeric_limits<int>::max()` and the comparison will always return true.

Comment: btw, your question would be much nicer if you could remove redundant stuff. Your code is basically doing the same thing 3 times. If you can fix it once, the other `cin`s are also fixed, so there is no need to include it in an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @tobi303, I removed it and gave it a very very large number. No exception thrown. Program behaving incorrectly. Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh279678.aspx

Comment: hm... seems like I was wrong, but honestly I am not convinced yet. As this msdn example is on error handling rather than numerical limits specifically, the example might be not the best demonstration of using numeric limits. I mean (by definition) the maximum value an int can hold is numeric_limits<int>::max(), so I dont get how this comparison can make sense. What happens if you use this check and type a large number?

Comment: @tobi303, If I type a large number and use this check, It throws the correct exception and works fine.

Comment: but it might be due to overflow and the throw is caused by the value being smaller than 0. Did you check this?

Comment: @tobi303, I personally agree with you but the compiler doesn't seemingly. I have edited and added this as a part of this question.

Comment: If you read into `double`, it will grab numbers until it finds a non-number, then the next `cin` gets the character and fails. If you need to test for `3d` as a whole, you need to read as a string then try parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using `operator>>(double &)` will first skip any whitespace characters, and then read character by character until a character is found that is not part of a number (e.g. a `p` or `x`, but not an `e` in case of `double`). This character is **left inside the stream** and the until then converted number returned. No error or failure is indicated.

([Example here](http://ideone.com/nPVMLU), unfortunately I couldn't find formal proof for my argument.)

To achieve the desired behaviour, you need to split reading and converting:

1. Read a token, probably terminated by whitespace, and
2. convert it into the desired value.

.

```
double read_side(std::istream & in) {
 std::string token;
 std::string::size_type next;
 in >> token;
 double result = std::stod(token, &next);
 if (next != token.size()) {
  throw std::invalid_argument("trailing characters");
 }
 return result;
}
```

[Live example here.](http://ideone.com/X2NtsM)

---

*I just noticed that you're now using `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, so the following does no longer apply to your code.*

Considering your question about the comparison: Your variables are of type `double`, so when you compare them to an integer value, that integer will first be converted to a `double`:

> [...] if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
>
> [N4431 §5/10.3]

And a `double` is able to store larger values than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.fail()` returns true if the last cin call failed.
Consider the input `2p 3p 4p`. This will work if you use `cin.ignore()` in between readings. `FirstSide` will be 2, `SecondSide` will be 3 and `ThirdSide` will be 4.

You could try clearing the stream and prompt the user for another input instead of throwing an exception.